# OpenPyxl cannot write VLOOKUP function to excel worksheet

Tags: python, excel, vlookup, openpyxl

I'm trying to write a VLOOKUP function using OpenPyxl to a column of cells. Everything about the code works just fine, except that excel crashes when I try to open the document after writing the functions to the cells.

I've tried writing the exact same functions but with within parentheses and then opening the excel document and removing the parentheses manually, which also works perfect. Then, Excel calculates the values exactly as it should.

I'm wondering if there's a formatting error going on? Is there anything I have overlooked when trying to write functions using Openpyxl?

Basically the code I want to work:

```
wb = load_workbook(path_result + '/' + 'File.xlsx')
ws = wb['Main 2018-04-17']

ws[{B}{2}].value = =VLOOKUP('Main 2018-04-17'!A2;'Data 2018-04-17'!C2:E100;2;FALSE)"

wb.save(path_result + '/' + 'File.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the documentation: you must use a comma to separate arguments. See http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-formulae